# How to mount S3 bucket as local FileSystem?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-s3fs

I have a python app running on a `Jupiter-notebook` on AWS. I loaded a `C-library` into my python code which expects a path to a file. 
I would like to access this file from the S3 bucket.

I tried to use s3fs:

```
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)
```

using `s3.ls('..')` lists all my bucket files... this is ok so far. But, the library I am using should actually use the s3 variable inside where I have no access. I can only pass the path to the c library.

Is there a way to mount the s3 bucket in a way, where I don't have to call 
`s3.open()`, and can just call `open(/path/to/s3)` were somewhere hidden the s3 bucket is really mounted as a local filesystem?

I think it should work like this without using s3. Because I can't change the library I am using internally to use the s3 variable...

```
with s3.open("path/to/s3/file",'w') as f:
      df.to_csv(f)

with open("path/to/s3/file",'w') as f:
      df.to_csv(f)
```

Or am I doing it completely wrong?

The c library iam using is loaded as DLL in python and i call a function :

```
lib.OpenFile(path/to/s3/file)
```

I have to pass the path to `s3` into the library OpenFile function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're looking to mount the S3 bucket as part of the file system, then use s3fs-fuse

https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse

That will make it part of the file system, and the regular file system functions will work as you would expect.

Comment: i thought s3fs is doing the same

Comment: The code you have is doing it in the context of a process; it is only available to that process. If you use Fuse, that makes it mounted at the system level, and the drive path available to all processes.

Answer (score 4):

If you are targeting **windows**, it is possible to use **rclone** along with **winfsp** to mount a S3 bucket as local FileSystem

The simplified  steps are :
`rclone config` to create a remote
`rclone mount remote:bucket *` to mount

https://github.com/rclone/rclone
https://rclone.org/

https://github.com/billziss-gh/winfsp
http://www.secfs.net/winfsp/

*Might not the completely relevant to this question, but I am certain it will be to a lot of users coming here.*

Answer (score 2):

after years aws introduces mountpoint a file client for s3 for linux [here](https://aws.amazon.com/de/about-aws/whats-new/2023/03/mountpoint-amazon-s3/)